# Sending confirmation alerts from Node/Express to Browser without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a web app with a working user authentication system. When the user updates their data, (e.g. email address or password) it sends a POST request to the server which in turn updates the database. I would like to have a bootstrap style block alert flash on the existing page upon success or error. Can I do this via a combination of (1) a `res.send` response from the server and (2) a jQuery script that watches for the `res.send` data and inserts the block alert HTML code into the browser?

The `app.post` block (which receives the updated user data via the post request) looks something like this:

```
app.post('/updateuser', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
[code here to update database]
res.send('[code to send to jQuery here]');
```

The HTML to render the block alert is:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>Success!</strong>User data has been updated.
</div>
```

If this is possible, what would (a) the server side `res.send` or similar and (b) client side jQuery code look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is connect-flash: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash

See the example https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/blob/master/examples/express3/views/index.ejs to display flash in your rendered template, or make an alert with the message if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using connect flash but was looking for an option that did not require reloading the page. I'll look into refactoring my code so that a reload is OK (the problem is the form sending the post is buried in a nav tab on the /settings page).

Comment: Consider having the form use AJAX rather than needing to do a full reload. connect-flash should still be effective within an AJAX form, which is just returning JSON.